# Java 8 stream get() on Optional - inside or outside the method?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I would like to know if there is any difference and which idea is better when using get() inside or outside the method. I operate on stream and I return its result to operate on it in the other class.

For example:

```
class FirstClass{
    //...

    public static Optional<MyObject1> myMethod(MyObject2 myObject2) {
        return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(a -> Objects.equals(a.getValue(), myObject2))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .findFirst();
    }
}
```

And then in the second class:

```
//...
MyObject1 myObject1 = firstClass.myMethod(myObject2).get();
```

OR:

```
class FirstClass{
    //...

    public static MyObject1 myMethod(MyObject2 myObject2) {
        return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(a -> Objects.equals(a.getValue(), myObject2))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .findFirst()
                .get();
    }
}
```

And:

```
//...
MyObject1 myObject1 = firstClass.myMethod(myObject2);
```

Comment: The first allows you to also utilize methods like `#ifPresent`, `#orElse`, etc

Comment: That should be out of question. You second method only works if you assume that the object is always present, as it would throw an exception otherwise. If that’s the case, you should never return an `Optional`. On the other hand, if the value is not assumed to be always present, you should not use a method that will break if the value is absent. So in either case, there is only one valid method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The first solution is better.**

`FirstClass` simply offers a method without knowing how it will be used. It just does what it is supposed to do, without being too prescriptive on the argument.

It is up to the caller to fail on the `get` if it wants to. Even better, the caller may want to handle the empty case and return a specific error or do further work.

Answer (score 1):

The java Optional type was made in an attempt to prevent `NullPointerExceptions`. Calling `#get()` on an empty optional (A possible result of `#firstFirst()`) would result in a `NoSuchElementException` being thrown at runtime. To avoid this issue, it is better practice to first check `if(myObject1.isPresent())` or `myObject1.ifPresent(unwrappedMyObject1 -> { ... });`.

If you don't want to use optionals in this way, either method above would work.